# java - how to check if field of List or Set type is empty?

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
for (final Field field : fields) {
    if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {

    }
}
```

How to check if field (which can be of List or Set type) is empty or null?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#isEmpty()

Comment: Also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
for (final Field field : fields)
{
    if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()))
    {
        field.setAccessible(true); // required if the field is not public (that is very likely)
        if (((Collection) field.get(object)).isEmpty()) // "object" being the object which owns your fields
        {
            System.out.println("Field is empty");
        }
    }
}
```